# Can static variables be allocated memory during run time

Tags: java, class, jvm, runtime

I am new to java and I am trying to understand the sequence in which JVM works.I have following queries.

1)Can a class be loaded at run time.

2)Can static variables be allocated memory during runtime.

3)Why static variables cannot be defined inside a function in java?

May be if you can explain me with the help of an example given below:

```
public class Test{
             public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
             static int d;
   }
}
```

In this example static is written inside a method which will give an error.It would be helpful if you can explain this with above context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply answers

1. Yes
2. Yes/No

details

1. You can load any java class in runtime, usually this is done via [Classloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)
2. All static variables are actually allocated and initialized by JVM (not you) during runtime, usually just before you use them, check out this answer: [Order of initialization of static variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936290/order-of-initialization-of-static-variable-in-java)

also you can re-allocate not final static variables in your code with new values/memory, like:

```
static String a = "a"; // default value to be used by JVM during init
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(a); // will print a, as JVM already initialized it with "a"
    a = "b"; // we've changed value
    System.out.println(a); // now will print b
}
```

but you cannot define static variable inside function, it is possible in c/c++, but not in java